# Какую сборку Opencart лучше использовать для создания интернет-магазина для русскоязычной среды

Tags: java, opencart, ocstore

У меня появилась нужда разработать интернет-магазин. Т.к. на spring + vue/react/jsf писать долго, решил выбрать opencart. Из того что я понял, ocStore является seo оптимизированной версией для русского сегмента, но там нет версии 3.*.

Подскажите пожалуйста следующее:

1. Какую версию и какой вид (т.е. ocStore, opencart-russian, opencart-pro или же оригинальную opencart) opencart выбрать?
2. Есть мощный CMS для Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу за Opencart, что там с Java я не знаю.

1) ocStore есть 3 версия https://ocstore.com/downloads

2) По сути не никакой разницы между этими сборками, но ocStore лучше в плане дополнительных полезных модулях и очень хорошая сео оптимизация.

3) Opencart Русская сборка является по сути оригинальной сборкой + немного дополнительных плюшек (есть третья версия).

4) По сути вы можете установить чистую версию, тогда модули нужно будет ставить отдельно.

Скажу за себя. Клиентам ставлю "Русскую сборку", потому что быстро. Для себя выбираю чистую, так как люблю, чтобы не было ничего лишнего.